# random image jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image, function, random

I have a jQuery file with the following code:

```
    ;(function($) {

    $.fn.randomImage = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var defaults = {images: [
                '<a href="page1.html">Asia<br><img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-CMBwAQFvgmc/ULwxL0ciUfI/AAAAAAAAAA8/RhaVA3N_TKM/s720/Asia.JPG" height=125 width=200></a>',
                '<a href="page2.html">Africa<br><img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-LZx9rZ_N7ZQ/ULwyGe1sOPI/AAAAAAAAABE/8iQpB5O7yys/s720/Africa.jpg" height=125 width=200></a>',
                '<a href="page3.html">America<br><img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-22FSGLZPiMU/ULwy2XZWWHI/AAAAAAAAABM/JgxWMAtQiuM/s800/Central America.JPG" height=125 width=200></a>']};
            var settings = $.extend(defaults, options || {});
            $(this).html(settings.images[Math.floor(Math.random() * settings.images.length)]);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I have introduce the following line into my HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="RandomPictures.js"></script>
```

And I have a HTML file to call the Jquery. I want to call it inside to a div.

How should I called?

I tried:

```
 <div id="header"><script>
$(function() {
      $('div').randomImage();
});</script></div>
```

But this hide all the elements in my HTML code and only appear the image.

I also tried:

```
 <div id="header"><script>
$(function() {
      $('header').randomImage();
});</script></div>
```

but the random image does not appears.

ANY ADVICE?

Answer (score 0):

For the second block of code, you need the `#` in your selector to target an id:

```
$('#header').randomImage();
```

---

For the first block of code, I'm not sure what you expected to happen.  The way your code is written, it finds all `div` tags and sets the `innerHTML` of every `div` to be your random image (which will likely wipe out the contents of your page).  That's what the code is written to do.  You should probably be targetting only a specific div that you want the random image in rather than all divs in the page.

---

In addition, the definition of randomImage that starts with:

```
$.fn.randomImage = ...
```

does not need to wait for the document to be ready and that could even cause a problem if the definition code doesn't run before you try to use it.  It only needs to be applied after jQuery has been loaded which you can accomplish with the load order of your scripts.